# Prove $\sup A \le \inf B$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $a < b$ for every $a\in A$  and $b\in B$. Prove $\sup A \leq \inf B$.

Do I need to start by proving $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ exist?
Then, how would I relate them?

Comment: Yes, that would be a very good place to start.

Comment: I'd go for contradiction.  Assume sup $A$ > inf $B$.  What can you prove from that?

Answer (score 4):

Any $ a\in A $ is a lower bound for $B$. So $ a\leq glb (B)$, where $ a $ is any element of $ A $. But this means that $ glb (B) $ is an upper bound for $ A $. So, $ lub (A) \leq glb (A) $.